# Why is my attempt link to a library I tried to find with CMake's find_library command with a path hint using $HOME not working?

Tags: cmake, build, .so

I have a papyrus project in Linux and I want to add a external library to be included in the cmake file in the papyrus project.

I have all the `.so` file in the location `cd $HOME/project/build`(`target.so`, `main.so`, etc.) directory.
Added the below code to the cmake but it gives me an error

```
FIND_LIBRARY(MYLIB NAMES target.so
           PATHS $HOME/project/build)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(program ${MYLIB})
```

I get an error in line - `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(program ${MYLIB})`.
so it just says- "*cmake error at line xx*". which is pointing to (TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES) - "*cannot specify link libraries for target "program" which is not built by this project.*"

Comment: you're getting an error message about the target. You need to show a [mre]. You haven't shown the definition of that target and the order of your command invocations.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet you meant to do `"$ENV{HOME}/project/build"` instead ([docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variable-references)). What you currently have is an attempt to expand a *CMake variable* named `HOME` instead of an *environment variable* named `HOME`. Expanding a CMake variable that doesn't exist gives an empty string, so your `PATHS` argument is really `/project/build`.

If you do `message("${MYLIB}")`, I'll bet you'll see `MYLIB-NOTFOUND` [as documented to happen when `find_library` finds nothing](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html).

Comment: I see. Thank you.I made the change as - "$ENV{HOME}/project/build" . After making the change I got the output for MYLIB

Comment: I still see the error in -TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES - which is the error I have mentioned in the post